# Iterate a pymongo cursor from MLab

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

Why won't the cursor iterate? I feel sure there *should* be an easy solution.

I have tried multiple Stack Overflow answers and the documentation for Mongodb
https://docs.mongodb.com/getting-started/python/query/

The code is as per below:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient

#Connect to Mongo Client 
client = MongoClient('mongodb://the_username:the_password@ds047124.mlab.com:47124/politicians_from_theage')
db = client.politicians_from_theage #define database used

# Define Collection
collection = db.posts
print collection
```

**Result:**

```
Collection(Database(MongoClient(host=['ds047124.mlab.com:47124'], document_class=dict, tz_aware=False, connect=True), u'politicians_from_theage'), u'posts')
```

Then the cursor will print its location:

```
# Define Cursor
my_cursor = collection.find()
print my_cursor
```

**Result:**

```
<pymongo.cursor.Cursor object at 0x0000000003247518>
```

Then to try and iterate over the cursor provides a timeout:

```
 # Perform query 
    cursor = db.posts.find()
    #Iterate the cursor and print the documents.
for document in cursor:
    print(document)  #No Luck
```

**Traceback Error or Iteration:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\PythonC\PythonWebScraping\17_MongoInterface\mongoget.py", line 18, in <module>
    for result_object in my_cursor:
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pymongo\cursor.py", line 1090, in next
    if len(self.__data) or self._refresh():
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pymongo\cursor.py", line 1012, in _refresh
    self.__read_concern))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pymongo\cursor.py", line 850, in __send_message
    **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pymongo\mongo_client.py", line 827, in _send_message_with_response
    server = topology.select_server(selector)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pymongo\topology.py", line 210, in select_server
    address))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pymongo\topology.py", line 186, in select_servers
    self._error_message(selector))
pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError: ds047124.mlab.com:47124: timed out
```

I have tried iterating on 'cursor', 'my_cursor' and 'collection', each of which provides a traceback error of server timeout.
Any help/insight would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer, I was focusing on the cursor rather than loading the object from the cursor from JSON to a list of JSON.

Final code is below (removing the URI)

```
import json
from datetime import date, timedelta
from pymongo import MongoClient
from bson import json_util

#Connect to Mongo Client 
client = MongoClient('mongodb://user:pword@ds047124.mlab.com:47124/politicians_from_theage')
db = client.politicians_from_theage #define database used
print db
# Define Collection
collection = db.posts
print collection # print Collection(Database(MongoClient(host=['ds047124.mlab.com:47124']...


cursor = collection.find()
print cursor

# Obtain json 
json_docs = []
for doc in cursor:
    json_doc = json.dumps(doc, default=json_util.default)
    json_docs.append(json_doc)
print json_docs #json result

# List Comprehension version
#json_docs = [json.dumps(doc, default=json_util.default) for doc in cursor]

#To get back from json again as string list
docs = [json.loads(j_doc, object_hook=json_util.object_hook) for j_doc in json_docs]
print docs

print 'kitty terminates program'
```

Answer (score 1):

This may help you:-

```
 # Perform query 
cursor = db.posts.find().toAray(function(err, result){
     #Iterate the cursor and print the documents.
     for document in result:
     print(document);
}) //Will give you array of objects.
```

Let me know if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
cursor = db.posts.find()
for document in list(cursor):
    print(document)
```